# Amazon s3 configuration in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have following Amazon s3 configuration:

```
   $Connection = new S3Client(array(
        'version'  => 'latest',
        'region'   => 'custom-region',
        'endpoint' => 'http://mydomine.com',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => AWS_KEY,
            'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
           // 'token' => false,
            //'canonical_id' => AWS_CANONICAL_ID,
           // 'canonical_name' => AWS_CANONICAL_NAME,
        ]
    ));
```

But calling this:

`print_r($Connection->listBuckets());`

I got:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception'
>   with message 'Error executing "ListBuckets" on
>   "http://mydomine.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: 400
>   InvalidArgument (client):  - `InvalidArgument`'
>
> exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client
>   error: 400' in
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:69
>   Stack trace: 0
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(199):
>   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>   1
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(152):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1,
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) 2
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(60):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() 3
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/guzzlehttp/gu in
>   /home/kristineg/public_html/ocr/scanning/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php
>   on line 152

As I understand, client is not configured correctly, but I can't imagine what exactly :(

Maybe somebody has any idea?

p.s. installed via composer like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/cache": "^1.4",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-resources": "^0.3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the object?

Comment: You can't just set your own `region` or `endpoint` that is not a Amazon endpoint, ie `http://mydomine.com`

Comment: But if service will host on my own hardware, not Amazon?

Comment: and how exactly are you planning to run your own Amazon S3 server?  That also defeats the purpose of cloud hosting.

Comment: @cmorrissey Via [link](http://ceph.com/). I can connect to my own disc using [link](http://www.dragondisk.com/), and I want to connect with php as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with older version, here I don't need to specify region. :)

```
$client = S3Client::factory([
        'key'    => Yii::$app->params['amazonS3']['accessKey'],
        'secret' => Yii::$app->params['amazonS3']['secretKey'],
        'base_url' => Yii::$app->params['amazonS3']['endpoint'],
    ]);
```